# Is Facebook giving me free ads while my app is waiting to be approved?

Tags: ios, facebook, ads

I just added the Facebook SDK to advertise my app on Facebook and only pay for installs.  Once I had the SDK working properly with Facebook receiving installation information I submitted my app to the app store.  As per usual, it will take about a week before apple reviews the app and releases the update.

Mean while, after submitting the app I went to Facebook and created a few ads for my app, the ads were approved with an hour and they went live.  Facebook is already reporting impressions and clicks but they have no way of knowing if those clicks resulted in installs because the version of my app with the Facebook SDK isn't live yet.

Does that mean that I could get getting free advertising while the update is waiting for approval?  Would my cost per install be higher once the app is approved if there is a week of ad impressions and clicks with no installs reported?

Anyone have experience with this?

In case anyone is wondering, I took the ads down because it isn't ethical not pay for the advertising.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging.  Looks like Facebook charges for impressions as well as per install when advertising an app.  Looks like there are no free lunches.  :)